# Spring Framework WebFlux Reactive Programming

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, webclient, spring-webclient

I am trying to send an object to the endpoint but I do not understand why I can't do it with .get(), why .post() has to be used? What if the endpoint method takes an object and does something with it and returns an object? I may want to send an object to the endpoint which takes the object as an argument. Is there a way to do it? How to pass a customer object to getCustomer() endpoint.

```
WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080")
            .get()//why this can not be used? why post has to be used?
            .uri("client/getCustomer")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .bodyValue(customer)//with .get() body cannot be passed.
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Customer.class);


        @GET
        @Path("/getCustomer")
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Customer getCustomer(Customer customer) {
            //do something
            return customer;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**

> In **GET** methods, the data is sent in the URL. just like:
>   http://www.test.com/users/1
>
> In **POST** methods, The data is stored in the **request body** of the
>   HTTP request.

**Therefore we should not expect .get() method to have .bodyValue().**

Now if you wanna send data using GET method, you should send them in the URL, like below snippet

```
   WebClient.create("http://localhost:8080")
            .get()
            .uri("client/getCustomer/{customerName}" , "testName")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Customer.class);
```

Useful Spring webClient sample:

[spring 5 WebClient and WebTestClient Tutorial with Examples](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-5-reactive-webclient-webtestclient-examples/)

Further information about POST and GET

[HTTP Request Methods](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Comment: I mean why I cannot use .get() and .bodyValue(customer) together? why .post() has to be used in order to send an object to end point as requestbody?

Comment: there is no rule about it. You can send (or omit) the body with **any** http method.

Comment: @Ritesh you can send data with both of them but in different ways. The GET requests cannot have a message body. But you still can send data to the server using the URL parameters

Comment: There is no such rule that says "The GET requests cannot have a message body".  You can send it if you want to. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061.